# If two of these segments have lengths 8 and 6, what are all possible lengths of the third segment?

Tags: geometry, plane-geometry, congruences-geometry

Please help me for this question, I can't fully understand the problem and not sure where and how to start.

In a plane, two congruent squares share a common vertex but have no other points in common vertex but have no other points in common. Connect pairs of the remaining six vertices to get three different parallel segments. If two of these segments have lengths 8 and 6, what are all possible lengths of the third segment?

Comment: Geometry means draw figure!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using the labelling of JeanMarie:

trapezoid $AA^{\prime}B^{\prime}B$ is isosceles. Drop perpendiculars and notice that the shorter leg of the right triangle is 1. Then notice that each triangle is congruent to triangle $CDO$. Hence segment $CD=1$ and so $CC^{\prime}$ is 2.

Answer (score 1):

Thought you might be interested in more solutions (may be even applied to the above more solutions).
I will leave you the computations of the various potential solutions (3?)

[image]

Answer (score 0):

The solution is 2. We prove it using complex numbers.

We take as real axis the axis of symmetry of the figure.

We denote the squares' vertices ABCD, and A'B'C'D', with primes attributed to symmetrical vertices as on figure below.

We take lowercase letters for the complex numbers associated with the corresponding uppercase letters.

Hypotheses: $ \ \ (H_1) \ AA'=6 \ \ and \ \ (H_2) \ BB'=8.$

We are going to show that $CC'=2.$

Let $s$ = side length of the square, and $\theta$ = polar angle of side $OA.$

We have: $a=se^{i\theta}, b=s(1+i)a.$

Using hypothesis $(H_1)$, we have: $a \sin \theta=1 \ \ (1).$

Besides, Consider the imaginary part of $s(1+i)(cos\theta + i\sin \theta).$

It is the half length of BB', i.e., we have, using hypothesis $(H_2)$:

$s(\cos\theta + \sin \theta)=4 \ \ (2).$

Substracting (1) from (2), on gets $\ a \cos \theta = 1 \ \ (3).$

Taking the quotient of (1) and (3): $ \ \tan \theta=3 \ \ (4).$

Using relationship $ \ 1+(\tan \theta)^2=1/(\cos \theta)^2$,

we get $\ \cos \theta=1/\sqrt{10} \ \ (5)$ and consequently $ \ \sin \theta=3/\sqrt{10} \ \ (6)$.

Using (5) in (3), we get $ \ s=\sqrt{10} \ \ (7)$.

Let $D$ be the projection of $C$ on the real-axis. Considering that angle O in triangle OCD is $\ \pi - (\theta +\pi/2) = \pi/2-\theta$, one has:

$\ CD=s \sin(\pi/2-\theta)=s \cos \theta=1 \ $ (using (5) and (7)).

Thus $ \ CC'=2CD=2$.

[image]

Comment: It seems that you used a way too heavy tool. From congruency of triangles the side of the squares may be determined easily as $\sqrt{1^2+3^2}$. It is straight forward by the same congruency to get your end result - A (1,3), B(-2,4) and C(-3,1)

Comment: Too complicated. Simple congruency of triangles leads to the single solution.

Comment: @motil I fully agree, here is another very simple way: set $A(a,3)$, $B(b,4)$,$C(c,h)$, write $\vec{OA}+\vec{OC}=\vec{OB}$, we get, $(a+c, h+3) = (b,4)$ from which $h=1$ !!!!!!!

Comment: trapezoid $AA^{\prime}B^{\prime}B$ is isosceles. Drop perpendiculars and notice that the shorter leg of the right triangle is 1. Then notice that each triangle is congruent to triangle $CDO$. Hence segment $CD=1$ and so $CC^{\prime}$ is 2.